# Finding $a$ and $b$ for the given polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots

Question:

> All the roots of $x^4 – 12x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 81 = 0$ are non-negative. The ordered pair $(a, b)$ can be?
> Options: 
> A) $(9,36)$ 
> B) $(27,-108)$
> C) $(54,-108)$ 
> D) $(36,108)$

Here. I eliminated option (A) and (D) as $b$ must be negative. But I was unable to calculate the value of $a$ as it required solving quite complex equations which were beyond my scope. Following were the equations:

> $\alpha +\beta +\gamma +\delta = 12$ 
> $\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \alpha\delta + \beta\gamma + \beta\delta + \gamma\delta = a$ 
> $\alpha \beta \gamma +\alpha \beta \delta + \alpha \gamma \delta + \beta \gamma \delta = -b$ 
> $\alpha \beta \gamma \delta = 81$

This must not be the way to go about finding $a$ but I can't think of anything else. Please help.

Answer:

> Option (C)

Comment: Do you know A.M ,G.M inequality and when equality holds? Then you are done.

Comment: Choice $ \ \mathbf{(C)} \ $ makes the polynomial $ \ (x - 3)^4 \ \ : \ $  the multiplicity  4 real zero sure is non-negative...

Comment: @boojum after the semicolon I didn't quite get you

Comment: The polynomial is a binomial to the fourth power and it only has one real zero, which is $ \ 3 \ $ four times.

Comment: @boojum Well, now you have arisen one more question that since it has only one real zero, then why does the question calls it has $4$? Is it allowed?

Comment: The problem does not say that the zeroes are _distinct_:  a fourth-degree polynomial has four zeroes, _counting multiplicities_.  It looks to me like one is supposed to notice (since this is a "contest-math" problem) that the polynomial could be $ \ x^4 + 4·x^3·(-3) + 6·x^2·(-3)^2 + 4·x·(-3)^3 + (-3)^4 \ \ $ and that choice is available.

Comment: @boojum alright, got it. Thanks a lot! Great answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

$x^4 – 12x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 81 = 0$

Let $\alpha, \beta ,\gamma ,\delta$ are four non negative roots.

Then

1. $\alpha +\beta +\gamma +\delta = 12$
2. $\alpha \beta \gamma \delta = 81$

Then $\frac{\alpha +\beta +\gamma +\delta}{4}=3=(81)^{\frac{1}{4}}=(\alpha \beta \gamma \delta) ^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Hence Arithmetic mean of $\alpha ,\beta, \gamma ,\delta $ is equal to geometric mean (A.M=G.M) .

Hence $\alpha= \beta= \gamma =\delta $.

From $1$ , $\alpha +\alpha+\alpha+\alpha=12$ implies $\alpha=3$

Hence $3$ is root of multiplicity $4$.

Now from the remaining two relations between roots and coefficients, we have

$\begin{align}a&=\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \alpha\delta + \beta\gamma + \beta\delta + \gamma\delta\\&=6\cdot 3^2 \end{align}$

$\implies a=54$

---

$\begin{align}-b&=\alpha \beta \gamma +\alpha \beta \delta + \alpha \gamma \delta + \beta \gamma \delta\\& =4\cdot 3^3\end{align}$

$\implies b=-108$

Comment: Wow! Nice. Upvoted. Had no idea it could come handy here too! How did you know it could be useful here?

Answer (score 0):

By the Descartes’ rule of signs, $b$ must be negative and $a$ positive.
Notice that the  constant term of the equation is a perfect square. This is our motivation for the goal to convert the expression to the form (if possible) $$(x^2+cx+9)^2=0.$$ This will give us $x^2+cx+9=0$. Again, by the Descartes’ rule of signs, $c$ must be negative.

Thus, comparing coefficients between $$x^4+2cx^3+(c^2+18)x^2+18cx+81=0$$ and $$x^4 – 12x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 81 = 0,$$ we get $$2c=-12\implies c=-6$$ so that $$a=54, b=-108.$$

Comment: Wow! Nice answer. Upvoted. I guess this involves a little bit of luck that the expression can be indeed converted to the "square" form, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. This is because ___both___ a and b are left unspecified. If one of them was specified, I would have acknowledged some luck. So you can basically keep changing the coefficient of $x^3$ and all such expressions will be convertible

Comment: So, (in simple terms) are you saying that since $a$ and $b$ are not given so it must be "square" form or else the question is unsolvable?

Comment: There is no “or else”. It _has_ to be “square” form.

Comment: @insipidintegrator "*This is because both a and b are left unspecified*" $\;-\;$ No, that's not the reason why you are getting the right answer in the end. Your "luck" here is that $\,12/4 = \sqrt[4]{81}\,$ which forces the roots to be equal when they are non-negative reals. Your approach will not work for other, similar problems.

Comment: @dxiv wouldn’t we be able to do the same for $x^4-16x^3+ax^2+bx+81$? We could compare it to $(x^2-8x+9)^2$. Could you give an example about what you want to say?

Comment: @insipidintegrator That's _assuming_ $\,x^4 - 16 x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 81 = (x^2 + cx + 9)^2\,$ but you nowhere justify that assumption. Suppose you are given this polynomial with the choices 1) $\,(0,0)\,$ and 2) $\,(81,-143)\,$. The correct answer would be 2) but you couldn't prove it with your approach.